# Javascript: value not the same between console.log

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I know this will get down votes :), but I have to ask in case someone has ran into something similar.

I can't post the code, because to duplicate it would take quite an effort.

But, in short, I have an object Table. This object has some functions called duplicate (Table.prototype.duplicate), rotate (Table.prototype.rotate), etc.

So you end up with something like this:

```
var Table = function(o){
  $.extend(this, o);
  console.log(this._options.rotate); //Returns 49 -- How does it seems to skip?
}
Table.prototype.duplicate = function(){
  console.log(this.rotate()); //Returns 49 -- this is set from elsewhere, not in this example
  var n = {}
  n._options = {
    rotate:this.rotate()
  }
  console.log(this.rotate()); //Returns 49
  console.log(n._options.rotate); //Returns 49
  console.log(n); //Returns {_options:{rotate:0}} -- Why and HOW??
  return n;
}
Table.prototype.rotate = function(){
  //returns css transform angle
}

var table = new Table();
var nt = table.duplicate();
console.log(nt); //Returns {_options:{rotate:0}} -- still 0 here, but look in constructor
var table2 = new Table(nt);
```

The code is more complex than that, but that is the jist of it. Basically, two console.logs in a row seem to produce different results.

After the call to the function, it still reports a 0 value. But when passed back to the constructor, it has it's value again.

Can you think of why I would be seeing something like this?

Thanks.

**Solution**
As pointed out by Felix King, using JSON.stringify(n) grabs the current value instead of Webkit's lazy loading value

Comment: Maybe it's this problem: [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196).

Comment: Trust debugger, not `console.log()` :-)

Comment: OH MY GOSH!  I have just spent hours thinking something was wrong with my code. Using JSON.stringify(n) works.  I guess it was just lazy evaluation.  What a bummer. Thanks so much Felix!